# Como colocar socket em modo leitura até receber outro dado em java

Tags: java, socket

Criei a parte do server e a parte do cliente. Se a troca de mensagens for apenas uma entrada e uma saída funciona perfeitamente, o problema é para manter uma comunicação sem fechar o socket.

No caso eu envio uma mensagem para o server, este responde confirmando o recebimento. No lado do cliente envio uma confirmação de recebimento e o server então envia a resultado da operação.

Existe alguma forma de fazer o método de leitura do lado do servidor ficar aguardando uma nova entrada? Quando eu faço a leitura novamente o método acaba lendo a primeira entrada do cliente, pois ainda não foi feito uma nova entrada. Poderiam me ajudar ?

Segue o meu código...

Cliente

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException;

public class Cliente {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        try {

            Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 40005);
            String resposta = null;
            String mensagem = "#Jose Alvaro#";
            socket.setSoTimeout(18000);
            socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
            DataOutputStream saida = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader entrada = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            resposta = enviarSolicitacaoExecucao(entrada, saida, mensagem);
            System.out.println(resposta);
            enviarConfirmacaoRecebimentoResposta(entrada, saida, mensagem, resposta);
            resposta = lerResposta(entrada, (char) 0);
            System.out.println(resposta);
            socket.close();
            /*
             * if(StringUtil.isNull(resposta)){
             * System.out.println("Resposta é nula"); }
             */
            // resposta = limparBinariosResposta(resposta);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    private static String lerResposta(BufferedReader entrada, char charactereEsperado) throws IOException {

        StringBuilder respostaBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String resposta = null;

        char[] charBuffer = new char[8192];
        int bytesLidos = 0;
        do {
            try {
                bytesLidos = entrada.read(charBuffer);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Erro" + e.getMessage());
            }
            respostaBuilder.append(new String(charBuffer, 0, bytesLidos).trim());
        } while (charactereEsperado != 0 && charBuffer[bytesLidos - 1] != charactereEsperado);

        resposta = respostaBuilder.toString();
        // System.out.println(resposta);

        return resposta;
    }

    private static void enviarConfirmacaoRecebimentoResposta(BufferedReader entrada, DataOutputStream saida,
            String mensagem, String resposta) throws IOException, ServiceException {

        /*
         * if (!validarConfirmacaoRecebimento(mensagem.getId(), resposta)) {
         * System.out.
         * println("Resposta não contem confirmação de recebimento do EOC"); }
         * 
         */ String confirmacao = "2 requisicao" + "\n";// mensagem.montarConfirmacao();

        saida.writeBytes(confirmacao);

    }

    private static String enviarSolicitacaoExecucao(BufferedReader entrada, DataOutputStream saida, String mensagem)
            throws IOException {

        String resposta = null;

        String solicitacao = ",,,..PRATPR";

        saida.writeBytes(solicitacao + "\n");
        resposta = lerResposta(entrada, (char) 0);

        return resposta;
    }

}
```

Server:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

     try {

           // Cria um SocketServer (Socket característico de um servidor)
           ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(40005);
           System.out.println("Socket iniciado OK");



           while(true) {

               Socket connectionSocket = socket.accept();
               BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));

               // Cria uma stream de sáida para retorno das informações ao cliente
               DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());

               (new ServidorSoc(connectionSocket,inFromClient,outToClient )).start();
           }
     }
     catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println(e);
     }
 }

}

public void run() {
        try {
            boolean continuar = true;
            while (continuar) {
                int cont = 1;
                String entrada = lerResposta(inFromClient, (char) 0);
                confirmacaoRec = retornarId(entrada) + confirmacaoRec;
                // System.out.println(entrada);
                // converte a resposta pra byte
                byte[] retorno = confirmacaoRec.getBytes();
                // escreve a mensagem no cliente
                outToClient.write(retorno);
                while (continuar) {
                    try {
                        sleep(10000);
                        // inFromClient.wait();
                        retornoCliente = lerResposta(inFromClient, (char) 0);
                        if (!entrada.equals(retornoCliente)) {
                            retorno = resp.getBytes();
                            outToClient.write(retorno);
                            continuar = false;
                        }
                        // System.out.println("Confirmação de recebimento" +
                        // retornoCliente);
                        // if (retornoCliente != entrada && retornoCliente !=
                        // null) {
                        // System.out.println(retornoCliente);
                        // }
                        // }
                        // sleep(1000);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

    }

    private String retornarId(String entrada3) {
        String[] s = entrada3.split("#");
        String resul = s[1];
        return resul.substring(0, 5);
    }

    private static String lerResposta(BufferedReader entrada, char charactereEsperado) throws IOException {

        StringBuilder respostaBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String resposta = null;

        char[] charBuffer = new char[8192];
        int bytesLidos = 0;
        do {
            try {
                bytesLidos = entrada.read(charBuffer);

                // System.out.println(bytesLidos);;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Erro" + e.getMessage());
            }
            respostaBuilder.append(new String(charBuffer, 0, bytesLidos).trim());
        } while (charactereEsperado != 0 && charBuffer[bytesLidos - 1] != charactereEsperado);

        resposta = respostaBuilder.toString();
        // System.out.println(resposta);

        return resposta;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Fiz um servidor de arquivos há dois anos na faculdade, irá solucionar seu problema. Ele tem 3 instâncias de servidor, um load balance (bem simples) e a parte do cliente. Vc inicia os servidores, depois o load balance e depois o cliente, os sockets aguardam as mensagens, recebem, tratam e retornam uma resposta para o cliente.

Controlador conecta no servidor:

```
static Socket controladorConectaServidor() {
        try {
            server_socket_alfa = new Socket("localhost", 9700);
            System.out.println("Conexão com AlfaServer realizada");
            return server_socket_alfa;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Nao consegui conectar com servidor alfa...");
            return null;
        }
    return null;
}
```

Servidor:

```
public class AlfaServer {

    static String endereco = ".\\src\\servidorAlfa\\";
    static ServerSocket serversocket;
    static Socket client_socket;
    static Conexao c;
    static String msg;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        new AlfaServer();
        do {
            servidorEscutaControlador();
            if (connect()) {

                "AQUI VEM AS FUNÇÕES QUE VOCE PREISA IMPLEMENTAR"
                }
                fechaConexao();
            }
        } while (true);
    }

    static boolean connect() {
        boolean ret;
        try {
            client_socket = serversocket.accept();
            ret = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Não fez conexão" + e.getMessage());
            ret = false;
        }
        return ret;
    }

    static void servidorEscutaControlador() {
        try {
            serversocket = new ServerSocket(9700);
            System.out.println("AlfaServer Escutando na porta: " + serversocket.getLocalPort());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Não foi possível criar o controlador");
        }
    }

    static void fechaConexao() {
        try {
            client_socket.close();
            serversocket.close();           // fase de desconexão
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Não encerrou a conexão corretamente" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Classe conexão:

```
public class Conexao {

    public static void send(Socket socket, Object obj) {
        ObjectOutputStream out;
        try {

            out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            out.writeObject(obj);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exceção no OutputStream");
        }
    }

    public static Object receive(Socket socket) {
        ObjectInputStream in;
        Object obj = null;
        try {
            in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            obj = in.readObject();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exceção no InputStream: " + e);
        }
        return obj;
    }
}
```

[Servidor de Arquivos (Github)](https://github.com/CaiqueCassemiro/ServidorDeArquivos)

Se tiver dúvidas manda mensagem que ajudo

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/150706)

Comment: Valeu pelo feedback @hugocsl , melhorei a resposta.